# Why does expand use different amounts of space characters?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, text-formatting

Why doesn't the expand command convert each tab character to exactly 8 space characters?

For example: `this^Iis^Itabs` *(`^I` represents a tab character)*

Becomes: `this____is______tabs____` *(underscores added to show spaces)*

Instead of: `this________is________tabs________`

From my testing, it looks like expand takes all the characters in a word boundary before the tab character, and then converts the tab into however many spaces it needs to add up to a total of 8 characters (including the characters within that word boundary).

Why is that?

The man page gives me no hints to this behavior.

Comment: TABs get you to the next TAB stop: the latter is supposed to occur at positions 8, 16, etc (or maybe 9, 17, ... - I don't remember any more). That's how they worked on typewriters: expand is just trying to simulate the same behavior. Basically, that's how you typed things in columns.

Comment: If you just want to replace tabs with a fixed number of spaces, use `sed`

Comment: @glennjackman I'm not trying to replace tabs with a fixed number of spaces, just trying to better understand the behavior of the expand command for my Linux+/LPIC 1 cert exam.

Comment: @Nick Ah, that makes a lot of sense. It's been a long time since I've used a typewriter. So that's where the column position is being determined. Thanks for that bit of info.

Comment: Might help to know that "tab" is short for "tabulation" which means "making a table". So of course it's all about aligning columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `expand` utility expands <kbd>tab</kbd> characters to the next implicit tab stop. Historically, and therefore by default, these are every eight characters, but you can change them with the `-t` option.

```
printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" 12345 1234 123
12345   1234    123

printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" 12345 1234 123 | expand
12345   1234    123

printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" 12345 1234 123 | expand -t 10
12345     1234      123

printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" 12345 1234 123 | expand -t 10,16
12345     1234  123
```

If you really just want to replace <kbd>tab</kbd> with eight spaces you could use `sed`:

```
printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" 12345 1234 123 | sed 's/\t/        /g'
```

Comment: @Jeff, tabs are usually every 8, so 8,16,24,32... There definitely won't be a tab stop at position 1.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly the *idea* of a tab, it jumps to the next column, a spot that doesn't change with the width of the previous field. For example the tabs here make the second column align nicely:

```
$ echo $'123\tfoobar\n123456\tblahblah'
123     foobar
123456  blahblah
```

With the same number of spaces on both lines, the result would be ugly:

```
123        foobar
123456        blahblah
```

With 8-character tab stops this of course only works if the values are 0 to 7 (or 8 to 15 etc) characters wide, variation over the 8-character limit again gives an ugly result:

```
$ echo $'123\tfoobar\n123.345e6\tblahblah'
123     foobar
123.345e6       blahblah
```

So that would require setting the tab stops to something different:

```
$ echo $'123\tfoobar\n123.345e6\tblahblah' | expand -t 12
123         foobar
123.345e6   blahblah
```

Instead of using tabs, the other way to make output like that would be to use `printf` with fixed-width fields (this is essentially similar to the output of `expand`):

```
$ printf "%-11 %s\n" 123 foobar 123.345e6 blahblah
123          foobar
123.345e6    blahblah
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed clarification. My confusion came from the documentation for the expand command. The line "convert tabs to spaces" was a bit misleading for me. If I had to rewrite it with the knowledge I gained from this thread, it would read: "converts tabs to spaces before the next tab stop". 

I see now that the `-t` value specifies where you want tab stops to be, not how many spaces a tab should be converted to.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page for `expand`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expand) *does* indicate that default tab spacing is eight characters:

> **-t**, **--tabs**=*NUMBER*
>
> have tabs NUMBER characters apart, not 8

The [info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/expand-invocation.html) (which the GNU project prefers to man pages) similarly states

> The default action is equivalent to `-t 8` (set tabs every 8 columns).

but is more explicit that tabs are every **x columns** in the terminal, not an insertion of **x space characters**.  As noted in a comment, tabs were formerly physical clips attached to the typewriter at specific offsets to allow moving forward to a specific column, for columnar formatting.

Comment: I know the default value for `-t` is 8 if not explicitly provided. My question was not about that. I was asking why a command that states it "converts tabs to spaces" doesn't convert every 1 tab into exactly 8 spaces; but you addressed that at the end of your answer. Thank you.